# Image hover transition on table - CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having list of images displayed on my webpage, and now i need to set different transitions for all image, that is when i hover to an image it should show one transition and for the second time hover it should show another transition
So that my question is how to set random trasnsition for a single image on hover using css

Comment: please provide fiddle of your code

Comment: Code please!! What have you tried??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope this will help you...

```
$('.photo').hover(function() {
    var a = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + a + 'deg) scale(1.25)');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set random transition but you can achieve through diff class names.

```
.transition1 {
/* transition1 css properties goes here*/
}
.transition2 {
/* transition2 css properties goes here*/
}
```

This can be acheived with jquery mouseover event:

- Initialise a variable with `0;`
- Increment when mouseover event triggers.
- Remove old classname and add new classname.

```
var n = 0;
$('.image')
  .mouseenter(function() {
    n = n + 1;
    $( this ).addClass('transition'+n);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).removeClass('transition'+n);
  });
```

The above jquery code will add new class names on mouseenter events. You can set multiple transition properties using this code.